# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' while using googletrans library

Tags: python

everything work before but it error now when i try using googletrans library. here my code

```
import googletrans    
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()
df['data'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
```

| 0 | tweet |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Heureusement que Macron n'a pas profité de la guerre en Ukraine pour être réélu mdr |
| 1 | L'Ukraine Ce pays formidable N'est-ce pas Macron le fou |

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-1c7cdbf959e6> in <module>
      4 
      5 translator = Translator()
----> 6 df['data'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
      7 
      8 df['data'].to_csv('Dataset_EN.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4136             else:
   4137                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4138                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4139 
   4140         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-4-1c7cdbf959e6> in <lambda>(x)
      4 
      5 translator = Translator()
----> 6 df['data'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
      7 
      8 df['data'].to_csv('Dataset_EN.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in translate(self, text, dest, src, **kwargs)
    180 
    181         origin = text
--> 182         data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
    183 
    184         # this code will be updated when the format is changed.

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\client.py in _translate(self, text, dest, src, override)
     76 
     77     def _translate(self, text, dest, src, override):
---> 78         token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
     79         params = utils.build_params(query=text, src=src, dest=dest,
     80                                     token=token, override=override)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in do(self, text)
    192 
    193     def do(self, text):
--> 194         self._update()
    195         tk = self.acquire(text)
    196         return tk

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py in _update(self)
     60 
     61         # this will be the same as python code after stripping out a reserved word 'var'
---> 62         code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
     63         # unescape special ascii characters such like a \x3d(=)
     64         code = code.encode().decode('unicode-escape')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and **ask a question**. Do not just show us some code and data. *What is supposed to happen* when you run the code? *What does happen instead*, and *how is that different*? When you say "everything work[ed] before", **what is** "everything"? If you get an error, please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and formatting it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code work properly for me. make sure you have the latest googletrans version or 4.0.0-rc1.

here for check your googletrans version

```
pip freeze
```

and here for install googletrans version 4.0.0-rc1

```
install googletrans==4.0.0-rc1
```